# Is there some way to make SASS/SCSS variables accessible without importing them in every component using Angular-CLI

Tags: angular, sass, less, global-variables, angular-cli

I'm working on some project with a lot of components. Just now I'm thinking about using SASS variables, but it could be annoying to import the variable into each existing component.
Maybe someone knows is there any way to make SASS variables accessible in all *.scss files in the project without importing them.

Comment: I'm not sure, but when I want a global css file I put it in the Styles section inside the angular-cli file. If you put your scss file in there, maybe the variables will be accessible from across the project without importing them.

Answer (score 10):

As of now answer to your question is '**NO**'. We have to import `variables` & `mixins` files in each of your component sass file.

angular-cli does provide configuration to  Add `paths/includePaths` functionality for `sass`. For that we have to add following config under `app` property.

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "style-paths"
  ]
}
```

Using above configuration at least we can directly `include` file by file name, skipping relative path like follows

```
@import 'variables';
```

For reference see [#3700](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3700) & documentation on [global-styles](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles).

Comment: As in the documentation, I've put in angular-cli.json, in apps object "stylePreprocessorOptions" with "includePaths" and the path to my variables. But unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: what you are trying to do & what error you are getting?

Comment: I'm trying to import file directly by name by adding to angular-cli.json, in object 'apps',    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "./src/assets/"
  ]
}, but i',m getting error: "Module build failed. @import 'variables'  - file not found or unreadable.

Comment: It works. Sorry, just deleted the last "/" at path))) Thanks a lot

Comment: This works but every time include a file, it's added to final output every time. Doesn't this hits the performance? Imagine if the included file is 300 lines long and added every time in the head of index.html.

Comment: @Samiullah nope, as Sass is a preprocessor which compile the sass script to css before loading on web page. During the process it removes all kind of variable & mixins. So it should not affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

To use a global scss, add your scss in angular-cli.json

```
"apps": [
   {
   // ... 
  "styles": [
     "./src/style.scss"
  ]
   }
]
```

and in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```